# What happens to TCP connection on socket timeout

Tags: java, c, linux, tcp, operating-system

Let's say we have a Java web client like spring `RestTemplate`. It can be configured with a read timeout:

```java
RestTemplateBuilder()
        .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
        .build()
```

If a http call is made and the server is slow to respond an exception would be thrown: `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`

The question is:
**what happens to the underlying TCP connection when the timeout occurs?**

From what I can tell `RestTemplate` uses `SocketInputStream` underneath which in turns uses native `poll` on Linux. `poll` accepts a timeout parameter, **but does it close the connection when the timeout occurs**? If not, what happens to the response when it is received?

How does the behavior of timeouts differs between Http1 and Http2 (which support multiplexing over a single TCP connection)?

Comment: At the socket level, nothing happens on timeout except that the call returns. You can imagine a polling loop where you check every now and then for data arrival, using the timeout to make sure you don't block for "too long" waiting.  That's amenable to simple experiment to verify.

Comment: @user16632363 so the connection is left hanging? When does it close if there is no response? after keep alive expires?  And what if there is a response after a timeout, is it discarded?

Comment: I'm far from an expert but I think that in consumer grade software, the socket call is either non-blocking or, if it is blocking, another thread is started to check for timeout. When there is a timeout, the socket is simply discarded (with close) and, if the server responds later, it is simply sent to the network card of the client and discarded. The OS isn't checking for arrival of packets since the connection is closed so it simply is not doing anything. Maybe the OS still receives the packets though. I'm not so sure since I never wrote an Ethernet/WIFI driver.

Comment: It's not "left hanging".  A timed-out poll leaves the socket and the underlying TCP connection in the same state as you not having called poll at all.  Received data stays in the socket until received. The socket closes when you call close.